# how to get drawable from string?

Tags: java, android

I have a string with value a drawable location in R class, like this:

`String myString = "R.drawable.ic_web_server"`

and I want to assign it's value to an int.

I tried `Integer.parseString(myString)` but it returns null int. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First get rid of the prefix `"R.drawable."`:

```
String s = myString.replace("R.drawable.", "");
```

and then get the `drawable`'s integer id with `getIdentifier()`:

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(s, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

`context` is a valid `Context` you must supply, or if your code is inside an activity you can omit it:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(s, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
String value= String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_web_server);
```

so you will have id of the resource and then you can use like

```
imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(value));
```

there is no need to convert to string. We can do it directly by integer

```
int value= R.drawable.ic_web_server;
imageView.setImageResource(value);
```

Comment: `R.drawable.ic_web_server` is an integer id. Why should it be converted to string and then back to integer?

Comment: we can do that directly by integer but i thought that he want to use string

Comment: The OP has a string and wants an integer id.

Comment: The OP does **not** have `R.drawable.ic_web_server` but a string: `String myString = "R.drawable.ic_web_server";`. Read the question again.

Comment: so the OP will get a string and then have to find that resource

Comment: And your code does nothing to get that resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Integer.parseInt(myString);
```

where you're using `parseString`.  Also you can try `valueOf` instead.

Comment: This will crash the app, because `myString = "R.drawable.ic_web_server"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code:

```
int i = R.drawable.ic_web_server;
```

Instead of:

```
String myString = "R.drawable.ic_web_server"
```

**OR**

```
String myString = String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_web_server);
```

Comment: The OP has: `String myString = "R.drawable.ic_web_server";` and the problem is to get the drawable's id by its string id. Read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get drawable image as string 
because it return int 
use directly to set image from drawable in imageview

```
 imageview.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo));
```

Comment: The OP does **not** have `R.drawable.ic_web_server` but a string: `String myString = "R.drawable.ic_web_server";`. Read the question again.